# how can I access the elements of a json object using javascript?

Tags: javascript

The data is as follows, produced by a Python script in a Flask app:

```
{"took": 0, "timed_out": false, "_shards": {"total": 1, "successful": 1, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0}, "hits": {"total": {"value": 3775, "relation": "eq"}, "max_score": 3.0824933, "hits": [{"_index": "ab", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "amjDgHABpFPexwJkaQM0", "_score": 3.0824933, "_source": {"reviews_per_month": "", "price": "150", "number_of_reviews": "0", "last_review": "", "host_id": "4632", "availability_365": "365", "id": "3647", "neighbourhood": "Harlem", "calculated_host_listings_count": "1", "neighbourhood_group": "Manhattan", "name": "THE VILLAGE OF HARLEM....NEW YORK !", "minimum_nights": "3", "longitude": "-73.9419", "host_name": "Elisabeth", "latitude": "40.80902", "room_type": "Private room"}}, {"_index": "ab", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "hmjDgHABpFPexwJkaQM0", "_score": 3.0824933, "_source": {"reviews_per_month": "2.04", "price": "50", "number_of_reviews": "242", "last_review": "01/06/2019", "host_id": "32294", "availability_365": "355", "id": "9668", "neighbourhood": "Harlem", "calculated_host_listings_count": "3", "neighbourhood_group": "Manhattan", "name": "front room/double bed", "minimum_nights": "3", "longitude": "-73.95104", "host_name": "Ssameer Or Trip", "latitude": "40.82245", "room_type": "Private room"}}, {"_index": "ab", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "h2jDgHABpFPexwJkaQM0", "_score": 3.0824933, "_source": {"reviews_per_month": "1.42", "price": "52", "number_of_reviews": "88", "last_review": "14/06/2019", "host_id": "32045", "availability_365": "255", "id": "9704", "neighbourhood": "Harlem", "calculated_host_listings_count": "1", "neighbourhood_group": "Manhattan", "name": "Spacious 1 bedroom in luxe building", "minimum_nights": "2", "longitude": "-73.95466", "host_name": "Teri", "latitude": "40.81305", "room_type": "Private room"}}]}}
```

I want to print elements of this data in to an HTML table on a web page, using JavaScript. The JavaScript code snippet is:

```
function test() {
fetch('https://exxxxh.azurewebsites.net/search') 
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['host_name']) 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['host_name'])
  }
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Before the for loop the console prints "Elisabeth" - the first host_name in the data. The for loop does not work and nothing is printed in the console log. How can I iterate through the data and extract all the host_names? And after that, of course, other elements. 
Thank you.

Comment: does `data` have a `length` property?

Comment: that is a very good question. I have assumed so but I don't know. The length is, in fact,3 because that is the limit of the search script in the Python app. Maybe we should work on that basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data['hits'] is an object, not an array.
data['hits']['hits'] is an array.

try this:

```
var hitsArray = data['hits']['hits'];
for (var i = 0; i < hitsArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(hitsArray[i]['_source']['host_name'])
}
```

Comment: thank you. All work, designed in their different ways, but this is precisely what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use for loop you can do this like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < input.hits.hits.length; i++) {
  console.log(input.hits.hits[i]._source.host_name);
}
```

OR you can use `.map` to get only the host name like this

```js
const input = {
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3775,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 3.0824933,
    "hits": [{
      "_index": "ab",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "amjDgHABpFPexwJkaQM0",
      "_score": 3.0824933,
      "_source": {
        "reviews_per_month": "",
        "price": "150",
        "number_of_reviews": "0",
        "last_review": "",
        "host_id": "4632",
        "availability_365": "365",
        "id": "3647",
        "neighbourhood": "Harlem",
        "calculated_host_listings_count": "1",
        "neighbourhood_group": "Manhattan",
        "name": "THE VILLAGE OF HARLEM....NEW YORK !",
        "minimum_nights": "3",
        "longitude": "-73.9419",
        "host_name": "Elisabeth",
        "latitude": "40.80902",
        "room_type": "Private room"
      }
    }, {
      "_index": "ab",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "hmjDgHABpFPexwJkaQM0",
      "_score": 3.0824933,
      "_source": {
        "reviews_per_month": "2.04",
        "price": "50",
        "number_of_reviews": "242",
        "last_review": "01/06/2019",
        "host_id": "32294",
        "availability_365": "355",
        "id": "9668",
        "neighbourhood": "Harlem",
        "calculated_host_listings_count": "3",
        "neighbourhood_group": "Manhattan",
        "name": "front room/double bed",
        "minimum_nights": "3",
        "longitude": "-73.95104",
        "host_name": "Ssameer Or Trip",
        "latitude": "40.82245",
        "room_type": "Private room"
      }
    }, {
      "_index": "ab",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "h2jDgHABpFPexwJkaQM0",
      "_score": 3.0824933,
      "_source": {
        "reviews_per_month": "1.42",
        "price": "52",
        "number_of_reviews": "88",
        "last_review": "14/06/2019",
        "host_id": "32045",
        "availability_365": "255",
        "id": "9704",
        "neighbourhood": "Harlem",
        "calculated_host_listings_count": "1",
        "neighbourhood_group": "Manhattan",
        "name": "Spacious 1 bedroom in luxe building",
        "minimum_nights": "2",
        "longitude": "-73.95466",
        "host_name": "Teri",
        "latitude": "40.81305",
        "room_type": "Private room"
      }
    }]
  }
};

const hostNames = input.hits.hits.map(i => i._source.host_name);
console.log(hostNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

If l understand correctly you want to take out value of every host_name inside input.hits.hits array.
Try:

```
getServerNames = () => {
  const serverNames = input.hits.hits.map(
    hit => hit._source.host_name);
  console.log(serverNames);
};
```

Result:

```
[ 'Elisabeth', 'Ssameer Or Trip', 'Teri' ]
```

Hope this helps.